# Long distance function call control

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, global-variables

I have a function fun10() that I modified to a function fun11().

A function fun1() calls fun2(), which calls fun3(), which calls, fun4(), ... and so on until fun9() calls fun10().

Since I modified fun10() to fun11(), fun9() calls fun11() instead of fun10().

However, I want to be able to choose whether I want to run fun10() or fun11(), based on my decision in fun1().

The source code is distributed over multiple .c and .h files in multiple folders.

Lots of C programming tricks are used, e.g. function pointers passed as arguments, opaque pointers to sub-structures in struct, struct and typedef in multiple levels, typecasting void pointers which are opaque handlers, tailq function iteration, back pointers, possible memory allocation for pointers etc.

I tried using a global variable as a flag with extern but it doesn’t work (error ‘unknown symbol’) maybe because fun1() does not recognize fun10().

Making a copy of every function in between seems too much especially when a function can contain hundreds of lines. I have a feeling this duplication is not good.

I haven’t tried modifying the number of arguments such as changing fun3(a, b) to fun3(a, b, int flag=0). What side effects would it have?

I am trying to squeeze the flag into one of the variables, which are often struct pointers, but it seems totally confusing because different struct pointers are passed from function to function. The final struct argument in fun10() ‘seems’ to be a subset of the struct argument in the original fun1() but it is contained inside a void pointer / opaque handler of the original struct definition.

What is the solution?

Comment: Assuming you want to switch functionally at run-time: 1st: Do not use a global flag, as this would obsfucate the functionally of the system even more. 2nd dive into the code, understand what is passed where and then modifiy it to pass the new info necessary down to where it is needed.

Comment: Default arguments are a C++ feature, it doesn't exist in C.

Comment: Thanks alk. I was initially tempted to plant global variables into multiple header files.

Comment: Thanks nm, lucky I didn't try default arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`fun1()` should *never* be interested in how exactly `fun2()` achieves what it's doing. It should only care about it working according to the specifications. It should not even know `fun3()` exists, not speaking about `fun11()`.

The only course of action that will not eat your brain later on is to have `f1()` pass its decision of what needs to be done to `f2()` in a parameter.

The same is true with respect to `f2()` and `f3()` of course. So you need to thread an additional argument through 10 levels of calls. Not such a big deal.

Comment: Thanks nm. Encouraging to know that it can be done. About the relationship between fun1() and fun10(), somehow I found that by modifying fun1() away from it original purpose to fun1b(), it was able to trigger fun10(). I had to use Notepad++, SourceInsight, and XMind to draw the function call diagram. Going forward from fun1() and backwards from fun10(), I was finally able to find the missing link.

Comment: For threading an additional argument through 10 levels of calls, a problem is that the entire source code is very complex so I don't want to modify the number of arguments. For every intermediate function, possibly multiple calls to the function are written at various locations and would therefore need to be changed if the number of arguments are modified.

Comment: The arguments are always struct variables. Whether they are pointers or not is quite confusing. I would have to create a new field in each unique struct variable to store the flag. It is the void pointer / opaque sub-structure and the tailq iteration that are most difficult for me now. Conceptually it sounds easy but when I am diving inside the codes things get out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a define directive

```
#define FCT10

#ifdef FCT10
#define FCT_TO_BE_USED(x) fct_10(x)
#else
#define FCT_TO_BE_USED(x) fct_11(x)
#endif
```

LE:maybe is not obvious -in fct_09 you will use FCT_TO_BE_USED(x);

Comment: No, this doesn't work I think. Preprocessor directives are executed before the code statements are compiled. I want to be able to choose during runtime.